# Convert Google Maps coordinates to projected EPSG:2154 CRS: RGF93 v1 / Lambert-93 with the sf R Packge

Tags: coordinate-system, sf, lambert-conformal-conic

This is the data I have in input:

```
> points
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  latitude   longitude
  <chr>      <chr>    
1 49.5150946 3.4798894
2 49.6635237 3.2990396
3 49.1200986 3.3175965
4 49.5638522 3.6248577
```

After some research I have come with this attempt that does not work:

```
city_proj <- "+proj=lcc +lat_1=43 +lat_2=62 +lat_0=30 +lon_0=10 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=intl +units=m +no_defs"
points <- st_as_sf(points, coords = c(1, 2))
st_crs(points) <- 2154
(new_points <- st_transform(points, crs = city_proj))
```

it leads to:

```
Simple feature collection with 4 features and 0 fields
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -1939867 ymin: -4828373 xmax: -1939867 ymax: -4828373
CRS:           +proj=lcc +lat_1=43 +lat_2=62 +lat_0=30 +lon_0=10 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=intl +units=m +no_defs
# A tibble: 4 × 1
             geometry
*         <POINT [m]>
1 (-1939867 -4828373)
2 (-1939867 -4828373)
3 (-1939867 -4828373)
4 (-1939867 -4828373)
```

I can see that the CRS is not okay, but I do not know how to set it up.

Comment: The proj4 definition I can find for Lambert-93 is different from the one you are using: '+proj=lcc +lat_0=46.5 +lon_0=3 +lat_1=49 +lat_2=44 +x_0=700000 +y_0=6600000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs'     [Source](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/rgf93-lambert-93/proj4/)

Comment: The CRS you are using is one for all of Europe--3034, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally understand how things work together.

##### Need to know which CRS (coordinate reference system) is used by both sides

- [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview) returns latitude/longitude in the [Hu-Tzu-Shan-1950](https://epsg.org/crs_4236/Hu-Tzu-Shan-1950.html?sessionkey=fennv72suc) CRS coded as ESPG:4236.
- The shapefile data I used for the map is in the [Lambert-93](https://epsg.org/crs_2154/RGF93-v1-Lambert-93.html?sessionkey=fennv72suc) CRS coded as EPSG:2154.

So here is the code needed to convert raw latitude/longitude numbers with the [`sf` package](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/):

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

## raw_coordinates as numbers from geocoding Google maps API
(
  tribble(
    ~ latitude,  ~ longitude,
    49.5150946,    3.4798894,
    49.6635237,    3.2990396,
    49.1200986,    3.3175965,
    49.5638522,    3.6248577
) -> raw_coordinates)

(  
  raw_coordinates
  %>% mutate(
    ## First transform them in geometric points
    st_point = map2(raw_coordinates$longitude,
                    raw_coordinates$latitude,
                    ~ c(.x, .y))
               %>% map(st_point),
    ## Create feature telling we are using ESPG:4236
    google_map_features = st_sfc(st_point, crs = 4236),
    ## Convert to ESPG:2154
    lambert93_features  = st_transform(google_map_features, crs = 2154)
  )
  %>% pull(lambert93_features)
)
```

which produces:

```
Geometry set for 4 features 
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 721601.7 ymin: 6891190 xmax: 745225.1 ymax: 6951643
Projected CRS: RGF93 v1 / Lambert-93
POINT (734765.9 6935191)
POINT (721601.7 6951643)
POINT (723185.3 6891190)
POINT (745225.1 6940689)
```

Comment: if the the data returned is long/lat then its not EPSG:4326. EPSG:4326 is lat/long

Comment: I have changed that in the text